# Webix DataTable with Widget Column Possible?

Tags: javascript, webix, webix-treetable

As like ExtJS/Sencha

[Extjs Widget Column Documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/guides/components/widgets_widgets_columns.html)

Is it possible to have widget columns in webix Datatable. I have requirement to draw range slider, combobox,checkboxes inside cell.

Answer (score 1):

There is some defaults widgets directly out of the box:

[Checkbox and radio widget inside table](https://snippet.webix.com/8fwq7idt)

But unfortunately not the slider one. Maybe you can use a subview or some kind of trick. Or maybe you should switch to a more complex widget like the DataLayout one:

[DataLayout with slider view inside it](https://snippet.webix.com/291dzu5k)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use cell template to achieve it. You can provide any HTML template to that.

https://docs.webix.com/datatable__templates.html

Comment: widget column i m expecting